# Change time in embedded youtube video when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube-api

I want to embed a youtube video and provide buttons which, when you click them goes to a specific time in the video and resumes playing from there.
I've tried using jquery and changing the "src" attribute, like so:

Original source:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PjDw3azfZWI?&t=5m30s&rel=0&amp">
```

JS:

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#video").attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/PjDw3azfZWI?&t=10m30s&rel=0&amp");
});
```

This caused the browser to refresh when I clicked the button.

Link to image of what I'm thinking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH0If.png. Clicking the buttons should make the video jump to the time specified.

Comment: adding `&t=37` where "37" is the amount of time into the video should do the trick. e.g. this is 19 seconds into this video... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoZ2kTlwKTk&t=19 (Stone Roses - Fool's Gold - in case you're wondering ;-)

Comment: That just refreshes the page

Comment: @Lightvvind, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @JustinPowell I got the player to work but the seekTo() function won't do anything. Other functions such as pauseVideo() does work.

Comment: @Lightvvind, I've added a fiddle to my answer.

Comment: @JustinPowell I got it working! Thank you! Do you know if it's possible to put the creation of the YT.player object in a separate .js file? It didn't work when I tried.

Comment: @Lightvvind, Should be able to. Make sure it's included prior to the YouTube API script. If you can't get it working feel free to post a sample.

Comment: @JustinPowell I got it working. Had to add the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady and the onPlayerReady parts outside of $(document).ready().
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't reload the iframe to control the video; use the Javascript API methods. Check out seekTo here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls

Basically, once your iframe loads, the JS API will call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(), where you construct a YouTube player object. Then you can use that player reference to control the video, such as player.seekTo().

You can still use your iframe, as described at the botton of [this section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player):

> As mentioned in the Getting started section, instead of writing an
>   empty  element on your page, which the player API's JavaScript
>   code will then replace with an  element, you could create the
>    tag yourself.
>
> ...
>
> If you do write the  tag, then when you construct the YT.Player object, you do not  need to specify values for the width and height, which are specified as attributes of the   tag, or the videoId and player parameters, which are are specified in the src URL.

The piece your code is missing is the YT.Player object, which you must construct in the callback method mentioned above. This provides access to player controls.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfa7v3dy/7/) demonstrating:

```
var player, seconds = 0;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("player");
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
      });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function seek(sec){
    if(player){
        seconds += sec;
        player.seekTo(seconds, true);
    }
}
```

You can put this code in a separate script, but make sure it is in the root scope (like in your head tag) instead of putting it in an onLoad handler.

Comment: how to do this with angulas js controller? I tried to have these functions in controller and then had api script loaded as well as resource. But still it doesn't work?